# stacking data from go routines

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm learning go lang and I'd like to create a go app to achieve the following:

1. receive data from a remote log
2. analyze some sort of error of warning
3. periodically send an HTTP request to a URL informing that everything is ok or send warn and error.

I've been reading about concurrency, parallelism and channels but I'm not sure how I should pass data from my logging goroutine to another routine with a timer to make the request.  Should I declare a slice in another routine to receive all the messages and at the end fo timer iterate over it?

currently, my code looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "gopkg.in/mcuadros/go-syslog.v2"
)

func strigAnalyze(str string){
/*analyse the contents of the log message and do something*/
}

func main() {

    channel := make(syslog.LogPartsChannel)
    handler := syslog.NewChannelHandler(channel)
    server := syslog.NewServer()
    server.SetFormat(syslog.RFC3164)
    server.SetHandler(handler)
    server.ListenUDP("0.0.0.0:8888")
    server.ListenTCP("0.0.0.0:8888")

    server.Boot()

    go func(channel syslog.LogPartsChannel) { 

        for logParts := range channel {
            content := logParts["content"]
            fmt.Println("logparts", logParts)
            string := fmt.Sprintf("%v", content)
            strigAnalyze(str) 
        }
    }(channel)
    server.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Should I declare a slice in another routine to receive all the 
messages and at the end fo timer iterate over it?**

This is one very common pattern in go. The example youre describe is sometimes called a "[monitor routine](https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/golang-monitors-and-mutexes-a-light-survey-84f04f9b7c09)". It guards the buffer of logs and because it "owns" them you know that they are safe from concurrent access.

The data is shared through the channel, the producer of the log data will be completely decoupled from how the sender is using it, all it needs to do is send on a channel. If the channel is unbuffered then your producer will block until the receiver can process. If you need to keep the producer high throughput you could buffer the channel or [shed sends](https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations), which would look like:

```
select {
   case logChan <- log:
      ...
   default:
     // chan is full shedding data.
}
```

This pattern also lends really well to a "receive" loop that `for...selects` over the input channel, the timer, and some sort of done/context. The following is not a working example and it is missing cancellation and logic but it shows how you can for...select over multiple channels (one of which is your timer/heartbeat):

```
logChan := make(chan string)

go func() {
   var logBuf []string
   t := time.NewTimer(time.Second * 5)
   for {
      select {
         log, ok := <-logChan:
            if !ok { return }
            logBuf = append(logBuf, log)
         <-t.C:
            // timer up
            // flush logs
            // reset slice
      }
   }
}()
```

Also depending on how you are using the data, it might make more sense to use an actual buffer here instead of a slice.